# Summarise data sacrificing the least resolution (creating groups of varying size based on a sum of lagged values)

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, grouping

Given a table with separate measures for different time points, I would like to summarise the table, based on the sum of values in column `measurement` of the current and previous time points. I would like to do this for every group of time points, where the sum of current + previous `measurement`s is below a certain threshold. Any row where `measurement` is above the cutoff should not be summarised.

Caveat: if the sum of two successive `measurement`s is above the threshold, but the next measurement is still below, it should be added to the next row.

Here is an example table:

```
d <- data.frame(name = c(rep("A", 8), rep("B", 8), rep("C", 8), rep("D", 8)),
                time = c(rep(c(1:8),4)),
                measurement = c(NA, 7, 17, 18, 30, 28, 24, 21,
                                1, 2, 3, 5, 18, 15, 38, 39,
                                11, 23, 67, 94, 405, 830, 1550, 2020,
                                25, 60, 200, 300, 1100, 2200, 3000, 3500))
```

I've tried introducing a column that I can use to `group_by` and then `summarise`, by using the sum of the current `measurement`, `lag(measurement, order_by = time)` and `lag(measurement, n = 2, order_by = time)` and asking if the sum of is above a threshold (eg. `20`). It's easy to see that this is pretty static and clumsy, though.

Also, in doing so, my initial test resulted in `name == A` being summarised, and all others are not.

What I'd like to achieve is:

```
   name time measurement
1     A    3          24
2     A    5          48
3     A    6          28
4     A    7          24
5     A    8          21
6     B    5          29
7     B    7          53
8     B    8          39
9     C    2          34
10    C    3          67
11    C    4          94
12    C    5         405
13    C    6         830
14    C    7        1550
15    C    8        2020
16    D    1          25
17    D    2          60
18    D    3         200
19    D    4         300
20    D    5        1100
21    D    6        2200
22    D    7        3000
23    D    8        3500
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need a conditional cumulative sum function. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53401644/2204410) you can make one with [r](/questions/tagged/r) of with [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) using [rcpp](/questions/tagged/rcpp). An adapted `c++`-version:

```
library(Rcpp)
boundedCumsum <- cppFunction('NumericVector boundedCumsum(NumericVector x) {
  int n = x.size();
  NumericVector out(n);
  double tmp;
  out[0] = x[0];
  for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i){
     tmp = out[i-1] + x[i];
     if(tmp > 20) 
        out[i] = 0;
     else 
        out[i] = tmp;
  }
  return out;
}')
```

Now, using [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) you could do:

```
library(data.table) # load the package
setDT(d)            # convert 'd' to a 'data.table'

d[is.na(measurement), measurement := 0
  ][, measurement := pmax(cumsum(measurement) * (shift(measurement, fill = 21) < 20), measurement)
    , by = .(name, grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, head(boundedCumsum(measurement) == 0, -1))))
    ][measurement > 20]
```

which gives:

> ```
>     name time measurement
>  1:    A    3          24
>  2:    A    5          48
>  3:    A    6          28
>  4:    A    7          24
>  5:    A    8          21
>  6:    B    5          29
>  7:    B    7          53
>  8:    B    8          39
>  9:    C    2          34
> 10:    C    3          67
> 11:    C    4          94
> 12:    C    5         405
> 13:    C    6         830
> 14:    C    7        1550
> 15:    C    8        2020
> 16:    D    1          25
> 17:    D    2          60
> 18:    D    3         200
> 19:    D    4         300
> 20:    D    5        1100
> 21:    D    6        2200
> 22:    D    7        3000
> 23:    D    8        3500
> ```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! I ended up not only summarising `measurement`, but other columns, so I had to modify it, but the `boundedCumsum` function was the golden ticket nonetheless!